# CAT ignores newline character

Tags: bash, newline

I am a learner and I just created a new bash script that reads two filesnames from the command line and prints their content concatenated. However, it doesn't work. I have two files: log1.txt and log2.txt, both of which end with newline. My code is basically this:

```
 File+=$(cat "$first")
 File+=$(cat "$second")
 echo "$File"
```

However, the end of the first file and the beginning of the second file are merged in a single line. How do I fix this? I've been googling for hours and I will appreciate any help.

Comment: Command substitution's documented, normal, anticipated, out-of-the-box behavior is to remove any trailing newline.

Comment: BTW, perhaps you wanted `File=$(<"$first")$'\n'$(<"$second")`? Bash-only, but much faster to execute (doesn't require any `/usr/bin/cat` executable but operates only using the shell's builtins).

Comment: ...to be clear: it's not `cat` removing your newlines. It's the command substitution -- `$(...)` -- that trims them, even if `cat` includes them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Command substitution trims any trailing newline in the output of the command run. This behavior is mandated by the POSIX standard -- and it would make no sense for it to be otherwise, as POSIX specifies that *all* valid lines of text on UNIXy systems must be terminated by a newline; so folks would be needing to trim trailing newlines constantly were it otherwise.

---

However, you have no reason to make it your shell's problem to introduce that newline:

`cat` stands for "concatenate"; when given multiple files, it concatenates them together. If you aren't passing it more than one argument, you typically have no good reason to use it in the first place.

```
File=$(cat "$first" "$second")
```

Comment: The number of files varies, what I wrote was just an example. I am running a for loop in $@ and for each file, I want to add it to the existing one. That's my problem

Comment: `File+=$'\n'"$(<"$file")"`, then.

Comment: ...or better, read into an _array_, not a string in the first place. `for file in "$@"; do Files+=( "$(<"$file")" ); done`

Comment: ...then you can `printf '%s\n' "${Files[@]}"` when you want to emit all their contents at a single time.

Comment: You can also `Files=$(cat -- "$@")` to do it all in one pass, just passing all your filenames through to `cat` and not needing to loop over them in bash at all.

Comment: Thank you for your time, I truly appreciate it. The problem is that the command line can receive arguments like this:
`./program log1.txt hello log2.txt` and therefore, when I parse and I arrive at an argument ending with .txt, I want to add it to the existing file.

Comment: @ampersander `files=( ); for arg; do [[ $arg = *.txt ]] && files+=( "$arg" ); done; FileContents=$(cat -- "${files[@]}")`

Comment: ...and of course, the `Files+=( "$(<"$file")" )` pattern I showed earlier will work in that case as well.

Comment: @ampersander why don't just parse the whole command line to get all files into a variable or an array then `cat` all of them at once?

Answer (score 0):

[Command substitutions](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution) remove any trailing newlines (even multiple newlines) at the end of standard output from the compound command inside. The two main ways around this is to either

1. make sure the command substitution ends in some other terminator which you then remove or
2. use something other than a command substitution.

A simple implementation of the first is this pattern:

```
name="$(some_command; echo x)"
name="${name%x}"
```

The simplest way to avoid command substitution is to concatenate each file to a separate file:

```
cleanup() {
    if [[ -d "$work_dir" ]]
    then
        rm --force --recursive "$work_dir"
    fi
}
trap cleanup EXIT
work_dir="$(mktemp --directory)"
aggregate_file="${work_dir}/aggregate"
cat "$first" > "$aggregate_file"
…
```